# I want to add auto play media in android

Tags: android, autoplay

I am working on integrating some video into one of my Activities. It plays fine, but I have to click play for it to actually play. I searched the forums and the developer site and cannot find anything relating to autoplay or autostart. Any suggestions?

MainActivity.java

```java
...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });


    VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    mVideoView.setVideoPath("file:///android_asset/video1.MP4");
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.seekTo(1);


    //mVideoView.requestFocus();
}
```

My contain_main.xml

```xml
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="imaker.MediaAutoPlay.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">

<VideoView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

</fragment>
```

Comment: mVideoView.start() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mVideoView.start()` for start video

to start video

or you can also use

```
mVideoView.seekTo(1)
```

Comment: Come on chat on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

**Auto Play Video like same as Facebook Youtube popular apps Popular Apps**

**Build.Gradle app module**

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.3'
 implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
 annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

[Auto Play](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cun0USnbMr8tgKmd95BKlTujIZvOJsPT/view?usp=sharing)

```
  public class  ExoPlayerRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

  private static final String TAG = "ExoPlayerRecyclerView";
  private static final String AppName = "Android ExoPlayer";
  /**
   * PlayerViewHolder UI component
   * Watch PlayerViewHolder class
   */
  private ImageView mediaCoverImage, volumeControl;
  private ProgressBar progressBar;
  private View viewHolderParent;
  private FrameLayout mediaContainer;
  private PlayerView videoSurfaceView;
  private SimpleExoPlayer videoPlayer;
  /**
   * variable declaration
   */
  // Media List
  private ArrayList<MediaObject> mediaObjects = new ArrayList<>();
  private int videoSurfaceDefaultHeight = 0;
  private int screenDefaultHeight = 0;
  private Context context;
  private int playPosition = -1;
  private boolean isVideoViewAdded;
  private RequestManager requestManager;
  // controlling volume state
  private VolumeState volumeState;
  private OnClickListener videoViewClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      toggleVolume();
    }
  };

  public ExoPlayerRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
  }

  public ExoPlayerRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
  }

  private void init(Context context) {
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    Display display = ((WindowManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
        getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))).getDefaultDisplay();
    Point point = new Point();
    display.getSize(point);

    videoSurfaceDefaultHeight = point.x;
    screenDefaultHeight = point.y;

    videoSurfaceView = new PlayerView(this.context);
    videoSurfaceView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
        new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector =
        new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

    //Create the player using ExoPlayerFactory
    videoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
    // Disable Player Control
    videoSurfaceView.setUseController(false);
    // Bind the player to the view.
    videoSurfaceView.setPlayer(videoPlayer);
    // Turn on Volume
    setVolumeControl(VolumeState.ON);

    addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
      @Override
      public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
          if (mediaCoverImage != null) {
            // show the old thumbnail
            mediaCoverImage.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
          }

          // There's a special case when the end of the list has been reached.
          // Need to handle that with this bit of logic
          if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
            playVideo(true);
          } else {
            playVideo(false);
          }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
      }
    });

    addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(new OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull View view) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull View view) {
        if (viewHolderParent != null && viewHolderParent.equals(view)) {
          resetVideoView();
        }
      }
    });

    videoPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, @Nullable Object manifest, int reason) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups,
          TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        switch (playbackState) {

          case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
            Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Buffering video.");
            if (progressBar != null) {
              progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }

            break;
          case Player.STATE_ENDED:
            Log.d(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Video ended.");
            videoPlayer.seekTo(0);
            break;
          case Player.STATE_IDLE:

            break;
          case Player.STATE_READY:
            Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Ready to play.");
            if (progressBar != null) {
              progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
            }
            if (!isVideoViewAdded) {
              addVideoView();
            }
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onSeekProcessed() {

      }
    });
  }

  public void playVideo(boolean isEndOfList) {

    int targetPosition;

    if (!isEndOfList) {
      int startPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
          getLayoutManager())).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
      int endPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();

      // if there is more than 2 list-items on the screen, set the difference to be 1
      if (endPosition - startPosition > 1) {
        endPosition = startPosition + 1;
      }

      // something is wrong. return.
      if (startPosition < 0 || endPosition < 0) {
        return;
      }

      // if there is more than 1 list-item on the screen
      if (startPosition != endPosition) {
        int startPositionVideoHeight = getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(startPosition);
        int endPositionVideoHeight = getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(endPosition);

        targetPosition =
            startPositionVideoHeight > endPositionVideoHeight ? startPosition : endPosition;
      } else {
        targetPosition = startPosition;
      }
    } else {
      targetPosition = mediaObjects.size() - 1;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "playVideo: target position: " + targetPosition);

    // video is already playing so return
    if (targetPosition == playPosition) {
      return;
    }

    // set the position of the list-item that is to be played
    playPosition = targetPosition;
    if (videoSurfaceView == null) {
      return;
    }

    // remove any old surface views from previously playing videos
    videoSurfaceView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    removeVideoView(videoSurfaceView);

    int currentPosition =
        targetPosition - ((LinearLayoutManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
            getLayoutManager())).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    View child = getChildAt(currentPosition);
    if (child == null) {
      return;
    }

    PlayerViewHolder holder = (PlayerViewHolder) child.getTag();
    if (holder == null) {
      playPosition = -1;
      return;
    }
    mediaCoverImage = holder.mediaCoverImage;
    progressBar = holder.progressBar;
    volumeControl = holder.volumeControl;
    viewHolderParent = holder.itemView;
    requestManager = holder.requestManager;
    mediaContainer = holder.mediaContainer;

    videoSurfaceView.setPlayer(videoPlayer);
    viewHolderParent.setOnClickListener(videoViewClickListener);

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
        context, Util.getUserAgent(context, AppName));
    String mediaUrl = mediaObjects.get(targetPosition).getUrl();
    if (mediaUrl != null) {
      MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
          .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaUrl));
      videoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
      videoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the visible region of the video surface on the screen.
   * if some is cut off, it will return less than the @videoSurfaceDefaultHeight
   */
  private int getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(int playPosition) {
    int at = playPosition - ((LinearLayoutManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
        getLayoutManager())).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    Log.d(TAG, "getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight: at: " + at);

    View child = getChildAt(at);
    if (child == null) {
      return 0;
    }

    int[] location = new int[2];
    child.getLocationInWindow(location);

    if (location[1] < 0) {
      return location[1] + videoSurfaceDefaultHeight;
    } else {
      return screenDefaultHeight - location[1];
    }
  }

  // Remove the old player
  private void removeVideoView(PlayerView videoView) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) videoView.getParent();
    if (parent == null) {
      return;
    }

    int index = parent.indexOfChild(videoView);
    if (index >= 0) {
      parent.removeViewAt(index);
      isVideoViewAdded = false;
      viewHolderParent.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
  }

  private void addVideoView() {
    mediaContainer.addView(videoSurfaceView);
    isVideoViewAdded = true;
    videoSurfaceView.requestFocus();
    videoSurfaceView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    videoSurfaceView.setAlpha(1);
    mediaCoverImage.setVisibility(GONE);
  }

  private void resetVideoView() {
    if (isVideoViewAdded) {
      removeVideoView(videoSurfaceView);
      playPosition = -1;
      videoSurfaceView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
      mediaCoverImage.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }
  }

  public void releasePlayer() {

    if (videoPlayer != null) {
      videoPlayer.release();
      videoPlayer = null;
    }

    viewHolderParent = null;
  }

  public void onPausePlayer() {
    if (videoPlayer != null) {
      videoPlayer.stop(true);
    }
  }

  private void toggleVolume() {
    if (videoPlayer != null) {
      if (volumeState == VolumeState.OFF) {
        Log.d(TAG, "togglePlaybackState: enabling volume.");
        setVolumeControl(VolumeState.ON);
      } else if (volumeState == VolumeState.ON) {
        Log.d(TAG, "togglePlaybackState: disabling volume.");
        setVolumeControl(VolumeState.OFF);
      }
    }
  }

  //public void onRestartPlayer() {
  //  if (videoPlayer != null) {
  //   playVideo(true);
  //  }
  //}

  private void setVolumeControl(VolumeState state) {
    volumeState = state;
    if (state == VolumeState.OFF) {
      videoPlayer.setVolume(0f);
      animateVolumeControl();
    } else if (state == VolumeState.ON) {
      videoPlayer.setVolume(1f);
      animateVolumeControl();
    }
  }

  private void animateVolumeControl() {
    if (volumeControl != null) {
      volumeControl.bringToFront();
      if (volumeState == VolumeState.OFF) {
        requestManager.load(R.drawable.ic_volume_off)
            .into(volumeControl);
      } else if (volumeState == VolumeState.ON) {
        requestManager.load(R.drawable.ic_volume_on)
            .into(volumeControl);
      }
      volumeControl.animate().cancel();

      volumeControl.setAlpha(1f);

      volumeControl.animate()
          .alpha(0f)
          .setDuration(600).setStartDelay(1000);
    }
  }

  public void setMediaObjects(ArrayList<MediaObject> mediaObjects) {
    this.mediaObjects = mediaObjects;
  }

  /**
   * Volume ENUM
   */
  private enum VolumeState {
    ON, OFF
  }
}
```

Comment: how to do this in fragment.. For example i am having 5 fragments and every fragment is having list of videos..how to stop video when i change the fragment.. this code is working fine for activity but not for fragments because even if a change the fragment video is getting played.. Please help.. Thanks !!

Comment: usign release() when you go from first fragment to other

Comment: can you explain a bit..release what?

Comment: its really good but i am facing one issue suppose we have image in list then then i. have to display image or suppose i am videoURl we have to  play video